# Error when trying to target and add classes to html, body, and __nuxt elements in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, getelementsbytagname

I'm getting the error "cannot read property 'classList' of null" when trying to add/remove classes using `document.getElementsByTagName('html').classList`, and also for any other high-level elements in the skies above Component Land, such as `body` or `__nuxt`.

Running in `mounted()` lifecycle with `nextTick` function.

Also tried checking `process.client`, but no luck either.

Any ideas?

Thanks : )

Comment: Do you actually have an element with the id "html"? Do you mean to use `getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: I definitely did. Thank you. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment above, you probably intended to use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

Just so you are aware, there are stored properties that reference the common HTML tags so you don't need to do any lookups:

```
document.documentElement  // <html>
document.body             // <body>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly and also taught me that I should log and inspect objects in the console when something simple doesn't seem to be working. When inspecting the HTML object, it's clear that the array index is necessary.

Answer (score -2):

When you start doing things like `document.getElementById('html').classList` and then the implied `.classList.add()` or `.classList.remove()` you get into the strongly discouraged practice of manipulating the dom outside of the vue instance and that can have unexpected consequences.

Vue allows the use of dynamic classes and class binding which should provide a much more elegant solution.

It's in the vue docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

Comment: I'm well familiar with dynamic classes. The issue here is regarding elements outside the scope of Nuxt. Nuxt uses a simple app.html to declare the `html` and `body` elements. It is not within an editable component, so other methods of action need to be taken.